# WebStorm wrong type annotation for discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, discord, discord.js

Currently I'm writing a new bot for discord, but the type annotation is wrong which means the autofill feature doesn't work correctly when I try to use the message listener.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image: here's what it's supposed to look like]

And this is what I get:

[image: And this is what I get]

It's not like it's impossible to do, since it still runs, but it'd be great if it'd work. Since I'm semi-reliant on the autofill feature to know if I'm doing something right.

It looks like discord somehow isn't imported correctly or something.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [WEB-44843](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44843) for updates.
As a workaround, you can use JSdoc to let the IDE know actual parameter type, like

```
client.on('message', /** Message*/message => {...}
```